# bitbucket Failed to connect

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was developing an app and working on bitbucket which suddenly I got this message without knowing the reason behind.

when I try to push, pull or even clone from the bitbucket

> fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused

That what I did to try solve this issue

1. try to ping the bitbucket.org and I got the Request timed out.
2. try to change the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and adding

   ```
   104.192.141.2 bitbucket.org
   ```

   then when I try ping again work fine but the website of the bitbucket did not , just works when the

   ```
   104.192.141.1 bitbucket.org
   ```

   In this case the request does not work.
3. change the proxy using

   ```
   git config --local http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
   ```

   I have also tried use

   ```
   git pull -4
   export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
   ```

   but no difference

My git version is 2.32.0.windows.1

I want to know the reason and how I can solve it.

Comment: Were you able to push, pull from that bitbucket repo earlier?

Comment: No , I want to fix it to continue my work . I am really stuck on this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have tried the steps from your research on this issue. Let me share things that I did to fix this.

Firstly remove all the tweaks you did so far in etc/hosts file, proxy, etc.

**Step1**: Since it is an organization account, ensure you're connected to VPN or SSO provider whichever is applicably needed.

**Step2**: Disconnect from your wireless and connect to mobile hotspot then try, since this could most likely be a service provider issue.

**Step3**: Remove origins and credentials of Bitbucket from your system

```
 git remote -v  // this will list all origins
 git remote remove origin
```

Credentials can be removed from [credential manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)

**Step4**: You're cloning through HTTPS link, create an access token, set the necessary permissions, and then try cloning the repository afresh.

Some helpful links for access tokens

[GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

[Bitbucket](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/integration-with-bitbucket-server.html#configure-bitbucket-integration)

**Step5**: In your .gitconfig file, delete the proxy settings

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

**Step6**: None of these steps from 2-5 above would help if you don't have access to the repository, it would say connection refused. Ensure you have the necessary permissions to the repository. If yes and you're connected to VPN or SSO as needed, then create a sample repo in GitHub and try push/pull from the same network.

If you have access to the repository and not able to access it, I must say, the above steps helped me resolve almost all the time. I recommended the same for anyone facing it and it did resolve.

Comment: I have created a new repo from bitbucket to try it to see if it will work , but unfortunately it does not . The same issue happened. I did like you said and removed the remote and proxy sitting and I still have this issue as well . GitHub works fine . I do not know why this happened to me suddenly when I was working normally .

Comment: It is more likely an access issue. Check with your IT tech support on your access to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue every once in a while and for me i unset the `remote.origin` and then add it again and it works..

```
git config --unset-all remote.origin.url
git config --add remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:<ORG>/<REPO>.git
```